# I am asking if this quantity has a name or it is just a real sequence.

Tags: polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Let us consider the Chebychev polynomial function $T_{n}(x)$ where $n$ is a **fixed** positive integer called the **degree** and $x$ is the real variable. Let us consider $x$ as a positive integer variable and consider the quantity $T_{x}(x)$. Clearly, this quantity is not a polynomial function. I am asking if it has a name. Or it is just a real sequence.

Comment: No name but interesting question ! $\to +1$

Comment: I added some more in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unusual but it has an expansion for small values of $x$
$$T_x(x)=1-\frac{\pi ^2 }{8}x^2+\frac{\pi }{2}x^3+\frac{\pi ^4-192}{384}
   x^4-\frac{\pi  \left(\pi ^2-4\right)}{48}  x^5+O\left(x^6\right)$$

**Edit**

If you look at the [trigonometric definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, we have

\begin{cases}
T_x(x) =\cos \left(x \cos ^{-1}(x)\right)           \qquad       
& \text{if}\quad |x| \le 1 \\
T_x(x) =\cosh \left(x \cosh ^{-1}(x)\right)         \qquad   
& \text{if}\quad x \ge 1 \\ 
T_x(x) =(-1)^x \cosh \left(x \cosh ^{-1}(-x)\right) \qquad 
& \text{if}\quad x \le -1  
\end{cases}